# Extracting div tags without any class and id using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get Hourly and Daily water level data from website using selenium.

my code so far

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Python27\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://hydrology.gov.np/#/basin/77?_k=1r1onx')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Hourly')]").click()
```

But its not working. I am new to selenium. I have also tried other methods to find elements but not succedded. I will appreciate any help in this regard.

code from the html

```
  div style="padding: 16px 0px; display: table-cell; user-select: none; width: 96px;">
    <div>
        <span tabindex="0" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 15px; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); line-height: 32px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; min-height: 32px; white-space: nowrap; background: none;">
            <div>
                <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px 24px; position: relative;">
                    <div>Point</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span tabindex="0" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 15px; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; color: rgb(255, 64, 129); line-height: 32px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; min-height: 32px; white-space: nowrap; background: none;">
            <div>
                <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px 24px; position: relative;">
                    <div>Hourly</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span tabindex="0" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 15px; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); line-height: 32px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; min-height: 32px; white-space: nowrap; background: none;">
            <div>
                <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px 24px; position: relative;">
                    <div>Daily</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you are stucking ? What is an error ? Kindly share Relevant HTML, And your code trial.

Comment: @ Ishita Shah I am not able to find the way to click on "Daily" .

Comment: Then you need to share sample block code of your HTML.

Comment: I have posted link for the website 'http://hydrology.gov.np/#/basin/77?_k=1r1onx'. I am also posting css code

Comment: Posting Link is never good reference, IT might lost in future and Referenced user might not go for original question. So Please include sample code in your question only.

Comment: @ Ishita Shah code updated in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//div[contains(text(),'Hourly')]` Your xpath seems correct as according to HTML, Please check with Debugger and you will be trace where the problem is,

You can click element by 3 ways:

1. driver.click()
2. Action Click

   `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

       targetElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Hourly')]")

       actions = ActionChains(driver)

       actions.move_to_element(targetElement).click().perform()`
3. javascript executor click

   `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Comment: @ Ishita Shah Thanks now dropdown is expanding but still not able to click on Point/Hourly/Daily do I need to use Select option and itereate over these to click??

Comment: Refer my updated answer, You can any of one method to click element. Make sure  you are clicking on correct element and its loaded before its get click.

Comment: Nope.....Till now not succeeded..... I am digging more about selenium as u mentioned above.

Comment: Got it just  I have to modify your code `actions.move_to_element(ele).click().send_keys('Daily').send_keys(u'\ue007').perform()`

Answer (score 1):

This

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Hourly')]").click()
```

using `find_elements` will return a list of elements. You'll have to iterate through the list to click on them.

To get the hourly data, you'll need to replace this line with

```
table_body = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.table.tab-bar > tbody')
print(table_body.text)
```

which will give data like

```
Jun 18, 2018 6:00 AM 1.94 -0.15 0.89
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 7:00 AM 1.93 1.92 1.93
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 8:00 AM 1.91 1.91 1.91
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 9:00 AM 1.9 1.89 1.89
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 10:00 AM 1.88 1.88 1.88
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 11:00 AM 1.87 1.87 1.87
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 12:00 PM 1.88 1.88 1.88
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 1:00 PM 1.88 1.87 1.88
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 2:00 PM 1.84 1.84 1.84
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 3:00 PM 1.86 1.84 1.85
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 4:00 PM 1.77 1.77 1.77
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 5:00 PM 1.68 1.68 1.68
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 6:00 PM 1.63 1.62 1.62
Mon, Jun 18, 2018 7:00 PM 1.62 1.62 1.62
```

Comment: Click on the button and then use the same two lines of code of the table to access the data, because the table doesn't change.

Comment: I stuck there, I am not able to find the link for the click using selenium. I want to make a list of all three options i.e. Point, Hourly and Daily after that iterate over them. but noble to find the link for these three options.